# How can a summoning circle dilute the effects of radiation over a wide surface area?

Tags: society, religion, power-sources, nuclear-power

Summoning circles are a way to communicate with entities within the ethereal realm from beyond the veil. A mage uses the summoning circle as a bridge to bring the entity from its realm and transporting it into the circle. It is generally the size of a large room and it creates a pocket reality which allows the entity to exist in-between realms while remaining in the mortal world. The entity is trapped within the zone and cannot move beyond its boundaries for the duration of its time here. The purpose of this is to provide a layer of protection for the summoner. These entities radiate their power in the form of etheral energies. This energy bleeds from the physical form of the entity and will overwhelm and ultimately kill mortals in the vicinity, and the zone that the circle creates contains that essence within it.

The Holy City holds special significance in the faith of this nation. Every 1000 years, the gods from the alternate realm cross over into the mortal world to spend time among their creations for the duration of one month. As they are gods, a larger circle is needed which encompasses the entire city. The priests would summon these gods through ancient rituals which would allow them passage and grant them the ability to walk the boundaries of the city. However, that still leave the problem of their radiating power which would be fatal to regular people. As mortals come from all over the world to the holy city to worship amongst the gods, this creates an issue. One would think that as the surface area of the city is much larger than a room, the spread would dilute the effects. But radiation doesn't work like that, as the winds and currents would carry these energies across the city and increase the damage, similar to the results of nuclear fallouts like Hiroshima and Chernobyl.

What can priests use to dilute the effects of the power of their gods to keep the inhabitants safer?

Comment: Summoning circle? you mean wormhole, do you know light can bend?

Answer (score 2):

Five possible options:

1. Personal Protection-Reverse the concept of the summoning circle to create a small field of protection around a mortal. This protection is gained by paying a certain fee to the priests and lasts for as long as the deities are walking the streets.
2. Transfiguration-Mere mortals can't take divine power? Well then....instead of protecting them, why not change them so they *can?* Special rituals reward worshippers for their devotion with a change in their very being, allowing them to endure an immortal's presence.
3. Acquired Immunity-By worshipping the gods in special, periodic rituals, would-be pilgrims are exposed to small amounts of divine power. Over time, they build up a tolerance, enough to take the deity's presence.
4. Divine Transformation-No, we're not turning the mortals into immortals or even divine for that matter. Instead, it's the *deities* that transform, taking on a form that doesn't threaten to kill worshippers by their mere presence.
5. Circle of Conversion-Centered on a diety; this magical dome converts dangerous divine power into something that won't kill the worshippers. These energies will likely bless whatever's exposed to them, making crops more bountiful, awakening the potential inside living things.

Answer (score 1):

Devise a way to drain the power into the summoning circle.  That way you protect the people from the power and can maintain a larger, stronger, longer-lasting circle than without it.